# Regardless of the extra spaces in username field

Tags: php

I want when the user enters his/her username such as  `my username is` in the username field, my  `php` code changes it to such a thing : `myusernameis` . How is possible this action?

Comment: Well post your php code so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: `$yourusername = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $yourusername );`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by two way.

First Way using str_replace

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

Second Way using preg_replace

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```